# how to create four input box in jquery first input and second input(+)third input(=) fourth input total value(-)first input

Tags: html, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

[image]

In first we have to input any number, in second we have to add the number,and in third total value (-) first input value if not same (like:eg:2nd) display message value are not same, In jquery have to do . plzz if someone could help.

Comment: "in second we have to add the number"? What number? I don't get the connection between the input boxes.

Comment: Please add your current code

Comment: This is not a platform to get readymade code you must provide your code.

Comment: here is the code at the bottom

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/rs2f8gvq/

Comment: this is the link

Answer (score 0):

```js
  $('.number').keyup(function() {
     var sum = 0;
    $('.number').each(function() {
        sum += Number($(this).val());
    });
    $('.total').val(sum);
     
});
```

```html
<input type="text" id="text1">
<input type="text" class="number" >+
<input type="text" class="number" >=
<input type="text" class="total" >

<!-- I want to substract 1st text input value and the last text total value if the values ar not same display message-->
```